About meromorphic 1-forms on complex manifolds.
Suppose that $M$ is complex manifold of dimension $m\geq 2$. By definition, a holomorphic $1$-form $\omega$ on $M$ is a holomorphic section of the holomorphic cotangent bundle (which is an holomorphic complex bundle of rank $m$). I have the following questions:

What is the definition of a meromorphic $1$-form on $M$?
If $\eta$ is a meromorphic $1$-form on $M$, what is the definition of
the divisor of $\eta$? In this case, what is its polar divisor?
Is the polar divisor an analytic subvariety of $M$?

In the book of Klaus Fritzsche and Hans Grauert, is presented the following:
If $\pi : L \to X$ be a holomorphic line bundle and $A \subseteq X$ an analytic hypersurface.
Definition 1:  A holomorphic section $s \in \mathcal{O}(X \setminus A, L)$ is called a meromorphic section over $X$ in $L$ if for every point $x \in X$ there is an open neighborhood $U = U(x) \subseteq X$, a function $h \in \mathcal{O}(U)$, and a holomorphic section $t \in \mathcal{O}(U, L)$ such that:
(1). $h \cdot s = t$ over $U \setminus A$.
(2). $\{p\in U : h(p)=0 \} \subseteq A \cap U$.
Also in the book of Phillip Griffiths, Joseph Harris they present the following:
If $ L \to M $ is a holomorphic line bundle, with trivializations $ \varphi_a : L|_{U_a} \to U_a \times \mathbb{C}$ over an open cover $\{ U_a \}$ of $M$ and transition functions $g_{ab}$ relative to $\{ \varphi_a \}$.
Definition 2:  A meromorphic section $s$ of $L$ over $U$ is given by a collection of meromorphic functions  $s_a \in \mathcal{M}(U\cap U_a)$ satisfying
$$s_a = g_{ab} s_b$$ in $U_a \cap U_b $.
Note that the quotient of two meromorphic sections $  s, s'\not\equiv 0$ of $L$ is a well-defined meromorphic function.
In both books, immediately after these definitions, the divisor of a meromorphic section is presented.
Therefore, in the case of meromorphic differential $1$-forms in $M$, which is the line bundle associated to the definitions 1 and 2?
Thanks

Have you tried looking anyone of those up in the literature? If so, what is it you did not understand?

Thanks for the observation, I found the following two definitions, which appear in the edit of the question.

I would say you need sections of arbitrary bundles, not just line bundles
